# Bad state: No element The relevant error-causing widget was HTML - Flutter

Tags: html, flutter, dart, wordpress-rest-api

We want to display the data on our wordpress website with the Html tag on the screen. The data is coming in the application, but I guess it does not convert Html. The reason for this is that there is a script tag among the data, I guess we are not sure. Can you help me ? How can we solve the problem?

we use flutter_html package.([link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html))

```
Widget _buildDescription() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(items.id.toString()),
        Html(data: items.title["rendered"]),
        Html(
          data: items.content["rendered"],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

[Debug Screen Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJoxh.png)

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qezkp.png)

[Screenshot after flutter_html:1.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5opha.jpg)

Comment: Here is the issue for the package: https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/issues/569

Comment: Yes the version is flutter_html package It works in 1.2.0, but it shows something like gist.github.com in the incoming data. The gist.github script does not work. How can I solve that problem?